# Looking for software to create an exact copy of the memory card

Tags: windows

What software can help me Copy memory card From my phone Into my hard disk My pc have Operating system is windows 7 My memory card Have two partitions, one FAT32 And second EXT Total memory 8 GB A MICRO-SD card Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: This question is more suitable in superuser.

Comment: you can mount your phone as a mass storage device then use windows to copy the files. or you can use ADB from the android SDK and do an "adb pull /sdcard/ c:/path/to/save/data/"

Comment: Or you can take your SD card out of the phone, place it into a card reader, and attach that to your Windows PC. It should be recognized automatically and will most likely even open directly in an explorer window.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for dumping partitions and devices is a unix tool called [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29), which is also available with almost any Linux distribution, like Ubuntu.

If you're running windows then you might want to try dd's counterpart for Windows - [WinDD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windd/).

It's usually:

`dd if=[source_inputfile] of=[sink_outputfile]`

## Warning!

These tool can do harm to your drives if used incorrectly (if you mix up data source and sink, the source will be overwritten). A quote from Wikipedia:

> It is jokingly said that dd stands for "disk destroyer", "data destroyer", "death and destruction", or "delete data", since when used for low-level operations on hard disks, a small mistake, such as reversing the if and of (input and output) parameters, could result in the loss of some or all data on a disk.

So please, be cautious.